# my php mail function doesn't seem to be sending me an email

Tags: php, function, email

My email function isn't working on my website. When I complete the form it doesn't send to my email address? What am I missing? Can anyone help steer me in the right direction?

```
<?php 
                // form submitted
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                // list variables
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $comment = $_POST['comment'];
                $company = $_POST['company'];
                $industry = $_POST['industry'];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];

                // email
                $to = 'myemail@example.com';
                $subject = 'Contact Form:';
                $emailBody = "
                Hi,
                <br /><br />
                <strong>Name</strong> : $name.<br />
                <strong>Phone</strong> : $phone.<br />
                <strong>Email</strong> : $email.<br />
                <strong>Company</strong> : $company.<br />
                <strong>Industry</strong> : $Industry.<br />
                <strong>Comments</strong> : $comment.";




                // mail

                if ($_POST['name']) {
                    } else {
                        echo "please specify your name<br>";
                    }


                if ($_POST['email']) {
                    } else {
                        echo "please specify your email<br>";
                    }

                if ($_POST['comment']) {
                    echo "Hi, $name, <br>
                    Thank you for the following comments: <br> <em>$comment</em>
                    <br>I will get back to you shortly at $email";
                    } else {
                        echo 'please specify your request';
                    }
                }

                if ($name && $email && $comments) {
                    mail('$to', '$subject', 'From: $emailBody'); 
                }  

                ?>
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: what do the mail logs say

Comment: I changed the string types in mail() however it is still not working.

Comment: nothing has gone through on their records (hosting plan)

Comment: Could you try sending a hardcoded mail instead? It could be a problem in the mail settings itself.

Comment: even if I comment all the other code and try the if statement with just the mail() function it doesn't work, and I get a blank page

Answer (score 2):

Basic PHP: You're using the **WRONG** string types:

```
mail('$to', '$subject', 'From: $emailBody'); 
     ^---^---
```

`'`-quoted strings do **NOT** expand variables. You're trying to send the email to an address which is the literal characters `$`, `t`, and `o`. For such "just a variable" usage, you won't need quotes AT ALL:

```
mail($to, $subject, "From: $emailBody");
                    ^---             ^--- note the different quotes here
```

Comment: thanks for your help and have changed the strings. I won't make that mistake again. However, it is still not being sent? Is there anything else I have done? I have been trying to figure it out for a couple of hours now.

Comment: This `if ($name && $email && $comments)` should be `if ($name && $email && $comment)` since you have `$comment = $_POST['comment'];` therefore no variable match, conditional statement fails and so does your `mail()` function @user3386102

Comment: thankyou, I fixed that mistake too. Unfortunately, it still isn't working. I am in touch with the hosting to see if it is in relation to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marc's answer: (*compliment, I should say*)

This `if ($name && $email && $comments)` should be `if ($name && $email && $comment)` since you have `$comment = $_POST['comment'];` therefore no variable match, the conditional statement fails because of it, and so will the `mail()` function.

Change to:

```
if ($name && $email && $comment) {
    mail($to, $subject, "From: $emailBody");
}
```